# The Species of the Houses

Tags: riddle, animals

There are six houses. Each house is owned by the same species, and has something written on top of it:

House 1: My name begins with what the first day begins with.
House 2: I find myself in a hot biome where it rains all year long.
House 3: Some people say my name is the sum of an amount of money.
House 4: Algumas pessoas dizem que eu moro onde se fala isso.
House 5: 55 million years ago something happened that eventually led to me.
House 6: The Reynard the Fox fable is related to me.

**What species are all the houses owned by?**

Comment: ROT13: Fcrpvrf vf vapbeerpg. Vg'f na vasenbeqre, cnenculyrgvp qrcraqvat ba jung lbh vapyhqr. Gurer ner znal qvssrerag fcrpvrf bs gur nafjre. Be whfg fnl navzny.

Comment: @justforplaylists 1. Why ROT13? 2. I will edit to be an animal

Comment: rot13 is used to hide spoilers in comments, since the usual spoiler-hiding format used in answers isn't available in comments

Comment: @samm82 but this wouldn't spoil anything

Comment: @The_AH Just wanted to be careful in case someone considered the exact taxonomic rank a hint. Probably doesn't matter much though.

Comment: @justforplaylists okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The houses are owned by

> monkeys

because

> 2 & 4. A hot biome where it rains all year and people speak Portuguese could be Brazil, where some monkeys live.
>  6. The only animal in the tales of Reynard that could be native to Brazil is Moneke, the son of Martin the Ape, who might be the source for the word monkey. [Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynard_the_Fox).
>  1. Sunday or Monday is usually thought of as the beginning of the week. Monkey and Monday both start with "Mon".
>  3. "Monkey" is slang for £500 in London. [Link](https://www.gocompare.com/money/funny-money).
>  5. Primates arose around the Paleocene-Eocene Thermal Maximum, about 55 mya. [Link](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/effects-of-climate-change-on-primate-evolution-141807385/).

Also,

> There are [six families](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey) of monkeys, five in the Americas and one in Africa / Asia.

Comment: Yep, your right! This was an easy one though.