# The Mysterious Animal 2

Tags: riddle, animals

Great, now that we know [the houses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121134/the-species-of-the-houses) are owned by

> monkeys

we can sell them to animal (n).

Animal (n) just said a few things!

1. For some reason people are sad that I apparently get blackmailed, often when I tell them what humans get out of me.
2. I eat a lot of verde.
3. I like bowing since it rhymes with me.
4. My name starts with the name of a common pet, sometimes.
5. A word that means "head" helped my name to develop.

**What animal is animal (n)?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty sure animal (n) is:

> Cows/Cattle

> 1. Likely has to do with being milked for all I got (a common phrase for being blackmailed) Thanks @Stiv!
>  2. Cows eat a lot of green grass
>  3. Cow rhymes with bow
>  4. Cat (a common pet) is the first 3 letters of Cattle
>  5. Cattle is derived from latin capitale (property/stock) which itself is derived from [capitalis](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cattle#etymonline_v_5503) (literally 'of the head')

Comment: Re 1, this may relate to rot13(['zvyxvat'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/milks) fbzrbar sbe nyy gurl'er jbegu)

Comment: Rot13(Ohg gura, vfa'g zvyx juvgr? Ubj jbhyq gung jbex jvgu "Oynpxznvy"?)

Comment: That's got to be it. Thanks @Stiv !

Comment: Rot 13(Gb nibvq pbashfvba, lbh fubhyq erqrsvar pncvgnyvf, fvapr fnlvat "Bs gur urnq" vafgrnq bs "Cevapvcny" be "Puvrs" znxrf crbcyr guvax bs gur yngva jbeq "pncvgvf", juvpu yvgrenyyl zrnaf "urnq".)

Comment: Yep, you got it right!